# Upgrade AngularJS to the latest Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

We have a legacy MVC web site that uses AngularJs (that is the version prior Angular 2) that we need to upgrade to the latest Angular. The thing is, this web site only uses Angular for databinding and some basic logic. So basically we are not using most of Angular functionality. It is not even a single page application, we have multiple pages and each is driven by a separate AngularJs controller.

I am a .net developer with zero Angular knowledge and I though it will be easy to migrate to the latest Angular. However all tutorials that I saw mentioned that I need to use node to install Angular and the install creates a SPA project. Instead, I need to integrate it to an existing MVC application and just use its databinding capabilities. Is this possible? Any starting points?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, migrating Angular with some versions gaps is never easy... even worse when you're talking about migrating from an old and different framework as AngularJS.

If you're a .net developer I would recommend to hire some good Angular dev with experience with these kind of huge migrations and also with these huge gaps. If it's not possible you should first try to learn the fundamentals of Angular. For example, if you look to Angular 2 and then angular 6 many things changed...so, imagine looking to the newest Angular 16 with signals, standalone components, etc it will be a lot of new things for you to handle it.

Apart from this, I would recommend to create a totally new project in Angular 16 (from scratch) and start doing the manual migration step by step and it will be a learning process as well for you.